# Can you die after the 'Knockout!'?

Tags: cuphead

Watching lets plays of Cuphead, I ofter see people beat the boss (get the 'Knockout!'), but there are still things that could kill it on the screen.

Can you die after the knockout? If you die after the Knockout, does it still count as a victory or defeat?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Technically, yes. A user on the Cuphead reddit named Edgarska produced this [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9IgG8q6l4ALPUMvK/giphy.gif) showing a knockout at the exact same time as the player death. According to the user, it counted as a win.

Comment: You can still die, but it seems that your status on the frame the Knockout was pronounced is what is carried over.